# "libstdc++ version must be at least 5.1", however the library version meets these requirements

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, llvm, ninja

I am currently trying to use a program that uses CMake and Ninja to build. My problem can be seen in the logs below.

```
-- clang project is enabled
-- clang-tools-extra project is enabled
-- compiler-rt project is enabled
-- cross-project-tests project is disabled
-- libc project is disabled
-- libclc project is disabled
-- libcxx project is enabled
-- libcxxabi project is enabled
-- libunwind project is enabled
-- lld project is enabled
-- lldb project is disabled
-- mlir project is disabled
-- openmp project is disabled
-- parallel-libs project is disabled
-- polly project is disabled
-- pstl project is disabled
-- flang project is disabled
-- Performing Test LLVM_LIBSTDCXX_MIN
-- Performing Test LLVM_LIBSTDCXX_MIN - Failed
CMake Error at cmake/modules/CheckCompilerVersion.cmake: 97 (message):
  libstdc++ version must be at least 5.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/config-ix.cmake:14 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:684 (include)
  

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occured!
```

I have installed libstdc++6, which makes me confused on what the problem is.
My system is the current version of Pop!-OS.

I have tried the following command to check if I have the library installed and on the newest version:

`sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`

I get this message: "libstdc++6 is already the newest version (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04)"

I have tried reinstalling the library with the following command:

`sudo apt install --reinstall libstdc++6`

But this has not changed anything and I still get the same error.

I have also done the commands above for g++, gcc and clang, but the error stays the same. All packages are up-to-date as well. I'm assuming that my problem is because of broken packages, but I have cleaned my broken packages and nothing has changed as well.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: 1) note: your image here should be converted to text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541. 2) "_If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them._" - Please ask a question instead of making a vague request for suggestions. See [ask]

Comment: 3) what project specifically are you building? LLVM? 4) "_I have also done the commands above for g++, gcc and clang_" - show exactly what commands you used to do that. 5) What compilers do you have installed, and exactly what versions of those compilers?

Comment: Do you have anything in /usr/local/lib and/or /usr/local/include?

Comment: Are you sure llvm is trying to link to the Gnu C++ library? (stdlibc++.so) and not with the Clang C++ library? (libcxx). The log shows "libcxx project is enabled".

Comment: `cmake/modules/CheckCompilerVersion.cmake` line 97 contains a small program. Make sure that program compiles.